# h2 database : RunScript compilation

Tags: h2

i am installing h2database in linux ubuntu.

I downloaded H2 Platform-independent.zip version 1.4.190

I ran build.sh

and executed

```
 prompt > java -classpath org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test -script test.sql
```

and also

```
java -cp h2*.jar  RunScript   jdbc:h2:~/test -user admin -script test.sql
```

i get error  " could not find or load main class RunScript"

I got to see that RunScript.java is not compiled.

the build.sh or build.bat doesnt compile RunScript.java.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:~/test -script test.sql
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, firstly i am not finding RunScript.class file. I can find the RunScript.java  in h2/src/main/org/hr/tools directory. when i build the h2database, i cant find the RunScript.class file. I am sure i cant execute without RunScript.class file!!

Comment: Is this Windows? How do you build H2? In which directory do you execute this?

Comment: h2Database for all platforms is available at http://www.h2database.com/h2-2015-10-11.zip  .   Unzip, you will find build.bat and build.sh for windows and linux.  i build from the unzipped directory where ever it is !